# Replace everything except price

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm extracting price from strings, which have different formats example below.

```
MRP 12,000
Rs. 12,000/-
Rs.12000.99
12000 after 10% discount
```

How can I use REGEX replace in C# to replace everything except price. I just need **12000** in my output, means numbers only allowed comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex**

```
(\d+.\d+)
```

**Test String**

```
MRP 12,000
Rs. 12,000/-
Rs.12000.99
12000 after 10% discount
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  1. [4-10]  `12,000`
- MATCH 2

  1. [15-21] `12,000`
- MATCH 3

  1. [27-35] `12000.99`
- MATCH 4

  1. [36-41] `12000`

**[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ1hT9/1)**

---

**EDIT**

here is another regex, it looks bit complex but it solves most of the issues mentioned in the comments. you may use the same if needed.

```
(?<=[\s.])(\d+(?(?=[\.,]\d).\d+|(?=\s|$)))
```

**[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ1hT9/3)**

Comment: This also catches things you don't wish to catch and doesn't get single digit amounts. The OP also says they don't want the period, only comma allowed: http://regex101.com/r/oQ1hT9/2

Comment: this will fulfill my need, @funkwurm is also correct where we don't know about input string. But since i know what is my input so accepting pushpraj. Thanks guys for your help

Comment: @funkwurm, See this update http://regex101.com/r/oQ1hT9/3, looks bit complex but I try to address solves most of such issues

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so for this particular use case. But you'd need more data to be sure that no other unwanted numbers are captured. For instance this might also catch phonenumber, so you'd have to adapt the negative lookbehind and lookahead to account for that.

```
(?<!\d\.)\b[\d,]+\b(?!%)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GHqlScacPqoy_2tl)

Comment: `For instance this might also catch phonenumber, so you'd have to adapt the negative lookbehind and lookahead to account for that.` Your regex does nothing to prevent that, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh that's exactly what I'm saying, I don't know the use-case so I don't know if this is something to account for or that we can assume no phone-numbers are present in the text we're analyzing.

Comment: @funkwurm no phone numbers will be present in input string. Only price + something extra(let say : MRP, Best Price, Rs. , Dollar, discount, EURO, $, '/-')